# jQuery addClass as Basis of Form Validation

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I am developing a form with a large number of fields and dynamic properties.  The basis of validation of required fields is based upon the inputs being assigned a class="req".

```
<input type="text" name="fieldname" class="req">
```

Validation function is run when the field changes:

```
$('.req').change (validate);
```

The validation is functional for all inputs which have the class hardcoded.  However, based upon the selection of a radio, a set of about 12 fields becomes required.  To accomplish this I am using addClass('req').  For these dynamically added field classes, validation is not run.

```
$("input:radio[name=second_owner]").click (function () {
 $('#owner2').hide();
 if ($(this).attr('id') == 'second_owner') {
  $('#owner2').show();
  $('input').each (function () {
   if ($(this).attr('name').indexOf('owner_2') >= 0) {
    $(this).addClass('req');
//  alert ($(this).attr('class'));
   }
  });
 }
});
```

The alert (when enabled) shows that the class has been assigned but the validation does not run when the fields are changed.  I am assuming that the array of required fields must be reloaded in some way in order for this to work.

Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: why not add `$(this).change(validate);` after `$(this).addClass('req');` ?

Answer (score 1):

Tom,

I'm in total agreement with Christian on this but I had some thoughts that might help you in structuring your form.

Instead of using a class 'reg', could you potentially use the disabled state of the additional elements?  You had mentioned that 12 fields become required depending on the state of a checkbox or radio button.  You could potentially do something like:

```
$('#my_checkbox').change(
    function(event) {
        if ($('#my_checkbox').prop('selected')) {
            // enable 12 fields here
        } else {
            // disable 12 fields here
        }
    }
);
```

Instead of just $('input'), you could do something more complex in your selector, such as:

```
$(':input:not(:disabled))')...
```

You may also want to consider some type of Form Manager to help you, especially if you have a large set of inputs.  This one comes to mind: http://borgboyone.github.io/jquery-form-manager/.  There are others out there as well.

A

Comment: Setting the input tags to disabled with the class="req", then changing the disabled attr in code did the trick.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`$('.req').change(validate)` only binds the `change` event to elements that have the `.req` class **at the time of execution**. This means if you add the `.req` class to elements after you've called `$('.req').change(validate)`, the `change` event will not be bound to those elements.

You have 2 options. You can either bind the change events to the element after you've added the `.req` class, for example:

```
$(this).addClass('req').change(validate);
```

Or you can use event delegation. Using [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/), you can bind the event to a parent element and pass in the optional child selector:

```
$('body').on('change', '.req', validate);
```

Replace `body` with a more suitable parent.